# How to Create a Gross,Expenses,and Net, of a Table on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have 2 tables:

```
1. Sales
+------------------------------+
|T_ID|TDate     |Product|Amount|
+------------------------------+
|1   |2019-07-28|Apple  |100   |
|2   |2019-07-28|Orange |100   
|3   |2019-07-29|Apple  |100   |
|4   |2019-07-29|Orange |100   |
|5   |2019-07-29|Orange |100   |
|6   |2019-07-29|Apple  |100   |
+------------------------------+

2. Expenses
+----+----------+--------------+------+
|T_ID|TDate     |Expense Type  |Amount|
+----+----------+--------------+------+
|1   |2019-07-28|Transportation|100   |
|2   |2019-07-29|Cash Advance  |100   |
|3   |2019-07-29|Transportation|100   |
+----+----------+--------------+------+
```

Is it posible to Get this kind of Output?
1st. The Product are Summed according to "TDate" and "Product" which is Outputted as "Gross".
2nd. The Expense are Summed according to "TDate" then Subtracted to the "Gross" which is Outputted as "Net".

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID|TDate     |Product|Amount|Quantity|Total|Gross|Expense|Net  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |2019-07-28|Apple  |100   |1       |100  |     |       |     |
|2 |2019-07-28|Orange |100   |1       |100  |200  |100    |100  |
|3 |2019-07-29|Apple  |100   |2       |200  |     |       |     |
|4 |2019-07-29|Orange |100   |2       |200  |400  |200    |200  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You want the gross,expense and net to be printed on the last row alphabetically by product on a day?

Comment: Where does quantity come from?

Comment: @forpas it is the the Count of Product for the certain day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a `SELECT JOIN` statement

```
select ss.T_ID, ss.TDate, ss.Product, ss.Amount,
       ss.Quantity, ss.Total, ee.Gross,
       expense, ee.Gross - expense as Net
  from
  (
  select min(s.T_ID) as T_ID, s.TDate, s.Product, avg(s.Amount) as Amount,
         count(s.TDate) as Quantity, sum(s.Amount) as Total              
    from Sales s
   group by s.TDate, s.Product
  ) ss
    left join ( select max(s.Product) as Product, 
                       max(e.T_ID) as T_ID,
                       count(distinct e.T_ID)*avg(e.amount) as expense, e.TDate,
                       sum(s.amount) as Gross
                  from Sales s left join Expenses e on e.TDate = s.TDate
                 group by e.TDate
               ) ee
    on ee.TDate = ss.TDate and ss.product = ee.product;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=60b392220412618b55392b421dd3586b)</kbd>

but I'm suspicious about the `Gross` column's result.